# How to let AWS lambda to pass a string value to index.html in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm currently building a lambda function which the iot trigger passes event['key'] value which based on the value of event['key'] it will update the index.html that is stored in s3 bucket. For example, if event['key'] = 'Yes', the html will display a string 'hi'.

I'm not quite sure how I'd be able to update html since I'm fairly new to AWS. I know there's like an API that has that functionality but can't seem to find it. putObject seems fairly close but it's not the one that I'm looking for since it needs to update the string value in html. Any way to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass a string value to index.html"? What/where is this HTML file and how to users access it? It sounds like you are wanting the HTML page to 'retrieve' the value sent via IoT?

Answer (score 0):

Details can vary based on environment / stack you using to write your Lambda.
If you want to update your index.html file located in S3 based on (IoT or any) trigger - your Lambda needs to getObject (read that file from S3) modify content - by simple find and replace or more advanced parsing, traversing, and DOM manipulation - and putObject back to S3.